Fourier Transform of a Triangular function (using the formula and the convolution theorem)
I am studying physics at a degree level, and I was given a seemingly simple question: FT of a triangular function. $\\f(x)=\frac{1}{a}(a-|x|)$ and I needed to show $\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc} \mathcal{F}[f]=a\sinc^2(\xi a/2)$
I tried using the standard Fourier transform formula and then tried using the convolution theorem. I reached the correct answer by using the formula, but I seem to have the scaling factor squared in the convolution approach (the FT of the rectangular function gives $a\cdot sinc(\frac{\xi a}{2})$).
What am I doing wrong? Why do I get an extra factor of $a$ in the other approach?
My full attempt:
$\\$


Thank you so much in advance!

I think all you write are right. This missing point is how to relate the result to $\mathcal{F}(f)$.
In fact $f(x) = (\Pi * \Pi)(x/a) = \frac1a \Pi(x/a) * \Pi(x/a)$ (because $\max f = 1)$, but not $\Pi(x/a) * \Pi(x/a)$.

Using $f(x) = (\Pi * \Pi)(x/a)$ (or $\Lambda(x/a)$ as you write), you first get $\mathcal{F}(\Pi * \Pi) = \operatorname{sinc}(\xi/2)$, and the next step (time scaling) introduces $a$ rather than $a^2$.
Using $f(x) = \frac1a \Pi(x/a) * \Pi(x/a)$, you get one of the $a$ cancelled.


Thank you very much! I was struggling with this for ages

@JeewooHan You're welcome! So could you mark my answer as "accepted"? It tells other people that the question is solved, and increases my reputation score.
To do so, click the green check mark, see https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.
